# How one can consecutively number the odd lines of a file?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

Want I want to do is simply add a column with the numbers of a huge file:

```
xxx xxxxx xxxx
xxx xxxxx xxxx
xxx xxxxx xxxx
xxx xxxxx xxxx
xxx xxxxx xxxx
```

To get the next output:

```
xxx 1 xxxx xxxxx
xxx xxxx xxxx
xxx 2 xxxx xxxxx
xxx xxxx xxxx
xxx 3 xxxx xxxxx
```

I tried something with `awk '{print NR % 2==1 etc ...}` but it doesn't work

Any suggestion?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're on the right track

```
awk 'NR%2 { $1 = $1" "++i}; 1;' file.txt
```

`NR%2` evalutes to true for odd-numbers lines. The resulting assignment replace the first field with the value in the first field plus a number that (starting from 0) is incremented then concatenated. The `1;` always evaluates to true and applies the default action (print) to the line. The longer-but-clear equivalent is `NR%2 { $1 = $1" "++i}; {print}`.

Comment: Thank you very much, It works properly, you the boss :)

Comment: Kudos for demonstrating the elegance of awk

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lane 'if ($. % 2 == 1){$n++; print "$F[0] $n @F[1..$#F]"} else{print}' file.txt
```

produces the output:

```
xxx 1 xxxxx xxxx
xxx xxxxx xxxx
xxx 2 xxxxx xxxx
xxx xxxxx xxxx
xxx 3 xxxxx xxxx
```

Explanation:

- `-n` loop around every line of the input file, put the line in the $_ variable, do not automatically print every line
- `-l` removes newlines before processing, and adds them back in afterwards
- `-a` autosplit mode – split input lines into the @F array.
- `-e` execute the perl code

`$.` is the line number

`@F` is the array of words in each line, indexed starting with 0
`$#F` is the number of words in `@F`
`@F[1..$#F]` is an array slice of element 1 through the last element